# What is meant by getTorrentObject?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I m using node js sdk to getTorrentObject. But I don't know what does torrent file mean?  Is is special kind of s3 objects?  I call then function on normal s3 object but it gives error method not allowed.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObjectTorrent.html

Comment: To the downvoters, while OP could have researched a bit more on what torrents are, the AWS documentation for this feature is hard to find unless you know that AWS documentation history is available in GitHub repos. Even the API documentation OP linked has a broken link to the removed page.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-userguide/blob/0d1759880ccb1818ab0f14129ba1321c519d2ac1/doc_source/S3Torrent.md

This is the last available version of AWS S3 documentation describing the torrent feature from the GitHub repository history. For some reason, AWS has completely buried the documentation even before the feature support end date is reached.

The most important part is:

> As of April 29, 2021 Amazon S3 is discontinuing the S3 BitTorrent feature and it will no longer be available to enable. AWS will support customers currently using the S3 BitTorrent feature for 12 months. After April 29, 2022, BitTorrent clients will no longer connect to Amazon S3.

The documentation also describes what BitTorrent is:

> BitTorrent is an open, peer-to-peer protocol for distributing files. You can use the BitTorrent protocol to retrieve any publicly-accessible object in Amazon S3.

Reasons your BitTorrent download might not work:

1. Your S3 object is not publicly-accessible.
2. You are using an AWS Region launched after May 30, 2016.
3. Object is larger than 5GB.